# Merge excel files from a folder with more than one tab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to build a solution that unifies all excel files in a folder and generates a new consolidated excel with all information. The files have the same amount of tabs (3) and same name.

I tried this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob


path = "C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\"
filenames = glob.glob(path + "\*.xlsx")
outputxlsx = pd.DataFrame()
for file in filenames:
   df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel( file, sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True, sort=False)
   outputxlsx = outputxlsx.append( df, ignore_index=True)
outputxlsx.to_excel("C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\Output.xlsx", index=False)
```

Unfortunately on the first tab the header is replicated and the other two tabs are not generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


def get_data_by_sheet(file_path: str) -> dict:
    return {x: df for x, df in pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None).items() if not df.empty}


path = "C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/"
all_files = [x for x in Path(path).rglob("*.xlsx")]

(pd
 .concat([pd.concat([df for sheet, df in list(get_data_by_sheet(file_path=file).items())]) for file in all_files])
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 ).to_excel(f"{path}final_df.xlsx", index=False)
```

Or if you also want to know what workbook and sheet each row came from:

```
(pd
 .concat(
    [pd.concat([df.assign(file_name=Path(file).stem).assign(sheet_name=sheet) for
     sheet, df in list(all_sheets_mapping(file_path=file).items())]) for file in all_files]
 ).reset_index(drop=True)).to_excel(f"{path}final_df.xlsx", index=False)
```